# CentOS installation: difference between live CD and live DVD

Tags: centos, system-installation, livecd

While I am trying to download the CentOS Live CD for the installation I have gone through something very new to me: install from a Live DVD. Up to now I have just gone through Live CD but what's the matter with Live DVD?

May I know what are the difference exists between Live CD and DVD?

Comment: in DVD you get more space... so more packages... so more applications / tools you can get.. That's it!

Comment: @Tejas Yeah Thank you but how can I what are the extras & benefits ? is there any way ?

Answer (score 1):

With CentOS they typically produce release notes which include details of what's included in both the Live CD and the Live DVD.

CentOS 6.4:

- http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOSLiveDVD6.4
- http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOSLiveCD6.4

These are always announced on the CentOS mailing list:

- http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/

All the release notes are available for all versions here:

- http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I didnt found in information in those links which can help me to know .

Comment: @Jai - maybe you can be more specific as to what information you're expecting? Full package list?